# How to copy properties from one Bean to Another and ignore nested Object's property

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a logic to copy properties from one bean to another bean in Java. I used BeanUtils to copy the properties and it works perfectly. Issue is that I want to ignore few properties of nested object but BeanUtils ignore properties work for only top level properties. Is there any util or library to do that ?
This is how my code is

```
class A{
 private String name;
 private List<B> bArr;
 }

Class B {
int age;
int taxID;
}
```

So I want to hide taxID from list of bArr. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...- just add properties you want to ignore in args

Comment: I tried to use IgnoreProperties and added list but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use modelmapper and config as you want!!

you have several ways to configure it

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```